# Query works on Oracle 11g but fails on Oracle 8i

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle8i

I am running this query in Oracle 11g with no problem:

```
select (case
         when seqnum = 1 then
          '1'
         when seqnum = cnt then
          '0'
       end) as value1,
       (case
         when seqnum = 1 then
          t.BEGIN_DT
         when seqnum = cnt then
          t.END_DT
       end) as TIME1,      
       t4.UNIT1 || '.SUBBATCH_TRIGGER' TAG     
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over(partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.plant_unit, t3.ID2 order by t.BEGIN_DT) as seqnum,
               count(*) over(partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.plant_unit, t3.ID2) as cnt
          from SCH2.tb_pg_unit_stap t
join (select ID1,batch_id from SCH2.VW_BATCH) t2 on t.BATCH_ID = t2.BATCH_ID
join (select ID2,ID1 from SCH1.STEP) t3 on t3.ID1 = t2.ID1) t
join SCH2.TB_W_MACHINE t4 on t4.plant_unit = t.plant_unit
where (seqnum = 1
    or seqnum = cnt) AND (t.BEGIN_DT > '01-jan-2013' AND t.BEGIN_DT < '01-feb-2013');
```

But when I run it in Oracle 8i (8.7.1) it gives ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Is there anys special consideration I must know for running sql commands in Oracle 8i?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 8i version of Oracle does not support ANSI join syntax(introduced in 9iR2). You'll have rewrite your query using comma(`,`) join notation(cross join), and place your join conditions in the `where` clause of the query.

Comment: oracle 8i: end of extended support 31-DEC-2006 (...shiver...)

Comment: I know it's a very old version, but I'm only developing some .NET stuff and I need to run this query there... It's the client's DB

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to CASE in Oracle 8i](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773779/alternatives-to-case-in-oracle-8i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAK case command was introduced since 9i.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Could someone help me rewriting it to Oracle 8i? I'm confused.

Comment: I'm really sure the problem is in row_number() and count(*) over, and this seems tricky to rewrite this query without analytic functions.

Comment: @simon: no it's not. They were available in in 8i - it's the ANSI `JOIN` that was not supported in 8.x

Comment: oh, you're right! I've simply never worked with anything less than 10g

Comment: My question was answered successfully. I'll open another question for the alternative to CASE. Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

OK - trip--down-memory-lane time:

```
select decode(seqnum,
                1,    '1',
                cnt,  '0') as value1,
       decode(seqnum,
                1,    t.BEGIN_DT,
                cnt,  t.END_DT) as TIME1,      
       t4.UNIT1 || '.SUBBATCH_TRIGGER' TAG     
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.plant_unit, t3.ID2
                                  order by t.BEGIN_DT) as seqnum,
               count(*) over (partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.plant_unit, t3.ID2) as cnt
          from SCH2.tb_pg_unit_stap t
          INNER join (select ID1, batch_id
                        from SCH2.VW_BATCH) t2
            on t.BATCH_ID = t2.BATCH_ID
          INNER join (select ID2, ID1
                        from SCH1.STEP) t3
            on t3.ID1 = t2.ID1) t
  INNER join SCH2.TB_W_MACHINE t4
    on t4.plant_unit = t.plant_unit
  where (seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt) AND
        (t.BEGIN_DT > '01-jan-2013' AND t.BEGIN_DT < '01-feb-2013');
```